# Only show fields that have content in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, logic

I have an app that has a product model and a product has the following attributes:

```
t.string :name
t.string :info
t.string :purpose
t.string :properties_sheen
t.string :properties_color
t.string :properties_solids
t.string :properties_coverage
t.string :properties_thickness
t.string :properties_flashpoint
t.string :properties_voc
t.string :application_ratio
t.string :application_thinner
t.string :application_method
t.string :application_cleaning
t.string :conditions_touch_5
t.string :conditions_touch_23
t.string :conditions_touch_30
t.string :conditions_hard_5
t.string :conditions_hard_23
t.string :conditions_hard_30
t.string :conditions_refloatation
t.string :conditions_interval_min_5
t.string :conditions_interval_min_23
t.string :conditions_interval_min_30
t.string :conditions_interval_max
t.string :coating_spec
t.string :surface_prep
t.string :storage
t.string :pack_size
```

On the product page these then fall into groups. For example Properties includes all the attributes with 'properties_' in etc.

What would be the best way for me to only show fields that have content in besides applying '.present?' logic to every attribute?

I have created some product helpers for the groups to try and remove complete sections that have no content but this doesn't seem very rails-y to me so I am sure there's a better way.

```
def any_applications_present?
  unless @product.application_ratio.present? || @product.application_thinner.present? || @product.application_method.present? || @product.application_cleaning.present?
    return false
  else
    return true
  end
end
```

Given that the app is simple and will feature perhaps 20 products maximum I am keen to keep the backend equally simple storing everything in a single products table ideally.

Any advice really would be much appreciated :)

```
**** Example from the Products Show View *****

.row
  .col-sm-12
     %h3
       Properties
     %p
       Sheen:
       %span
         = @product.properties_sheen
     %p
       Color:
       %span
         = @product.properties_color
```

Comment: You don't want to display fields which don't have content? Will they be NULL or have empty string `''` or whitespace?

Comment: They are wrapped by css <p> tags and so although the field is completely empty it's adding empty div tags. I have updated my question with a snippet from the view :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
# in product.rb
def has_applications?
  [:ratio, :thinner, :method, :cleaning].any? do |method|
    send("application_#{method}").present?
  end
end
```

then just call this on your model:

```
@product.has_application? # returns true or false
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to filter attributes before showing. For example, in controller:

```
@product = Product.first
```

in view:

```
.row
  .col-sm-12
     - @product.attributes.except('id', 'ctreated_at', 'updated_at').select{|attr, value| value == false || !value.blank? }.each do |attribute|
      %h3
        = attribute.humanize
      %span
         = @product[attribute]
```

Create an instance method in `Product` class:

```
def available_attributes
  self.attributes.except('id', 'ctreated_at', 'updated_at').select{|attr, value| value == false || !value.blank? }
end
```

now view can be:

```
.row
  .col-sm-12
     - @product.available_attributes.each do |attribute|
      %h3
        = attribute.humanize
      %span
         = @product[attribute]
```

Of course you will have to do some CSS styling here.

Also, at the place of `attribute` use `I18n`: `I18n.t(attribute)` to fetch the value you want to show:

```
en:
  properties_sheen: 'Sheen'
  properties_color: 'Color'
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer it's really helpful and will definitely work for some sections. The issue I have is that the sections aren't all the same format, some parts have tables, others are a string, some are numbers etc. Regardless this will definitely be helpful for the bulk. :)